# How do I give a user access to a folder of mine?

Tags: 12.04, ssh, permissions

So far I've set up an ssh server and added a user account using the GNOME "add user" dialog. Now login and sftp work, but I'd like to give this user read-only access to one of the folders in my /home directory. I should also note that I have an encrypted /home directory. I tried setting up a symbolic link to the folder, and then changing the permissions on the link, but that didn't seem to work. When I try to cd into that folder as that user, I get: `Couldn't canonicalise: Permission denied`.

Answer (score 1):

Just sync it to Ubuntu One and share it that way(you can share folders over U1).

Way easier than goofing around with how you're going to get your encrypted home to unlock if you're not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

The only method I could imaging would work would be to keep that particular directory unencrypted. The only way I know how to do that is to keep it outside the homedir.

```
sudo mkdir -p /public/$USER
sudo chown $USER: /public/$USER
chmod 0744 /public/$USER
ln -s /public/$USER ~/public
```

Then copy your shared stuff into `~/public`